# OVERLAPS for date without ts

Tags: oracle

I found out problem with condition to query, based on wm_overlaps.
I have two periods:

```
(29/04/2014; 30/04/2014)
(30/04/2014; 01/05/2014)
```

and query:

```
select * from dual
where (date'2014-04-29',date'2014-04-30') overlaps (date'2014-04-30',date'2014-05-01');
```

how can I make this work.
As I understand even in timestamp date'2014-04-30' = date'2014-04-30' so why this condition doesn't work?

Comment: Note: `overlaps` is an undocumented Oracle function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use explicit logic:

```
select *
from dual
where date '2014-04-29' <= date'2014-05-01' and
      date '2014-04-30' >= date'2014-04-30';
```

Two periods overlaps if the first starts before second ends, and the first ends after the second starts.

Comment: Mb there is some another function that could give me needed result? It's wery hard to rewrite all "overlaps" to this construction

Comment: Can I use wm_overlaps and wm_meets to solve this task?